# Why does my server never receive WebSocket send?

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I'm implementing a WebSocket server (for learning purposes) and I have it correctly handling the handshake (**websocket.onopen is called** so I assume this means handshake was successful), however, when the client (browser) sends a message after the handshake, the server never receives it.

Using Chrome's developer tools, I'm able to see that all the headers were correctly received and no errors are thrown. It also says that it sent the "hello" despite the readLine() never firing in Java.

What's wrong in my code?

**EDIT 1:** I discovered that if I refresh the web page, then (and only then) the ServerSocket receives the data from the last connection (that the refresh just killed)! Why is this the only way it receives it?

**EDIT 2:** I also found that I can send a message to the client after the handshake and the client receieves it but STILL the server never receives the client's message! I sent the message to the client like this:

```
byte[] message = new byte[ 7 ];
message[ 0 ] = new Integer(129).byteValue();
message[ 1 ] = new Integer(5).byteValue();
byte[] raw = "hello".getBytes();
message[ 2 ] = raw[ 0 ];
message[ 3 ] = raw[ 1 ];
message[ 4 ] = raw[ 2 ];
message[ 5 ] = raw[ 3 ];
message[ 6 ] = raw[ 4 ];
outStream.write( message);
out.println();
```

---

**HTML PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>WebSocket Test</title></head>

    <body>
        <script>
            try
            {
                function writeToScreen(message)
                {
                    var p = document.createElement( "p" );
                    p.innerHTML = message;
                    document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ].appendChild( p );
                }

                function onOpen(evt)
                {
                    writeToScreen( "opened" );
                    doSend( "hello" );
                    //We reach here but the server never recieves the message! (and bufferedAmount == 0)
                    writeToScreen( "sent: " + websocket.bufferedAmount );
                }
                function onClose(evt)
                {
                    alert( "closed" );
                    websocket.close();
                }
                function onMessage(evt)
                {
                    alert( "Message: " + evt.data );
                }
                function onError(evt)
                {
                    alert( "Error: " + evt );
                }

                function doSend (message)
                {   
                    websocket.send( message );
                }

                //PUT IN YOUR OWN LOCAL IP ADDRESS HERE TO GET IT TO WORK
                var websocket = new WebSocket( "ws://192.168.1.19:4444/" );
                websocket.onopen = onOpen;
                websocket.onclose = onClose;
                websocket.onmessage = onMessage;
                websocket.onerror = onError;

            }
            catch(e)
            {
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;

public class WebListener
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening) new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

        serverSocket.close();
    }
}

class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("ServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( outStream = socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine, outputLine;

            //Handle the headers first
            doHeaders( out, in );

            //Now read anything they have to send
            while ( ( inputLine = in.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                //WE NEVER REACH HERE!
                System.out.println( inputLine );
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doHeaders(PrintWriter out, BufferedReader in) throws Exception
    {
        String inputLine = null;
        String key = null;

        //Read the headers
        while ( ( inputLine = in.readLine() ) != null )
        {
            //Get the key
            if ( inputLine.startsWith( "Sec-WebSocket-Key" ) ) key = inputLine.substring( "Sec-WebSocket-Key: ".length() );

            //They're done
            if ( inputLine.equals( "" ) ) break;
        }

        //We need a key to continue
        if ( key == null ) throw new Exception( "No Sec-WebSocket-Key was passed!" );

        //Send our headers
        out.println( "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r" );
        out.println( "Upgrade: websocket\r" );
        out.println( "Connection: Upgrade\r" );
        out.println( "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + createOK( key ) + "\r" );
        out.println( "\r" );
    }

    public String createOK(String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception
    {
        String uid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
        String text = key + uid;

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );
        byte[] sha1hash = new byte[40];
        md.update( text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
        sha1hash = md.digest();

        return new String( base64( sha1hash ) );
    }

    public byte[] base64(byte[] bytes) throws Exception
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out_bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream out = new Base64.OutputStream(out_bytes); //Using http://iharder.net/base64
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();
        return out_bytes.toByteArray();
    }

    private String convertToHex(byte[] data) { 
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
            int two_halfs = 0;
            do { 
                if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9)) 
                    buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
                else 
                    buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
                halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
            } while(two_halfs++ < 1);
        } 
        return buf.toString();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket messages are not terminated by `\r\n` so you can't use `in.readline()` to read them.  See the [data framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) section of the spec for how to messages are constructed.

For text messages from client (browser) to server, messages will have the form:

- (byte)0x81
- 1, 3 or 9 byte structure indicating message length and whether the message body is masked.  (Messages from a browser should always be masked.)
- 4 byte mask
- Message (utf-8 encoded)

There is no end-of-message marker you can search for.  You just need to read the first few bytes of a client request to figure out the length of its payload.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue! I forgot to switch from the http protocol to the web sockets one.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols hasn't been accepted by web client yet, and client is still waiting for http response to complete with 2 CRLF.

Answer (score 1):

your code WebListener must running on windows, and you will find out line.separator is CRLF

```
    byte[] lineSeperator=System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes();
    System.out.println("line seperator: "+Arrays.toString(lineSeperator));
```

In your response header

```
    out.println( "Header xxxx"+ "\r" );
```

so header is ended with \r\r\n

Per HTTP [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6)

```
   Response      = Status-Line               ; Section 6.1
                   *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                    | response-header        ; Section 6.2
                    | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                   CRLF
                   [ message-body ]          ; Section 7.2
```

Client don't can not decode your header with \r\r\n.